# how to change/set columns on 'open file' file browser?

Tags: 22.04, nautilus, files, browser

when on a website, I need to upload a file, there's a browse button which opens a 'file open' file browser window. the problem I have is that I can't seem to be able to add columns so I can filter or order files by so i can find the specific set of files I want to  upload.

the only columns currently present are name, size, type and modified, but I want to see files by creation date, for instance, but I don't seem to be able to find how to add those columns there.
[image]

I tried to change default columns to show Created date in Files (Nautilus) using the dconf-editor and that seems to work for files, but it does not change the 'Open File´ File browser windows (which appears to be somehow different from Files/Naulilus)

[image]

thank you in advance for any help that can be provided.